# Regular Expression Validation In ActionScript

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I need to validate a regular expression aganist a string veryt strictly only what is there in string. But at present i don't see such a function for regular expression since bot exec and test doesn't check strictly. for example say i have regular expression for validating 43a^2b^2, but even its 43a it's returning true, as a part of string is present in reg exp. i need true only when exact match is found, is there any way achieve this?

The code I am using at present:

```
var isRegExp:Boolean = regExp.test(value1);
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Using the beginning of string `^` and end of string `$` tests should work.

```
var regExp:RegExp = /^43a$/;
regExp.test('43a'); //true
regExp.test('43a^2b^2'); //false
```

You can read more about anchors [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).